# MISRA 20.2 Violation misunderstanding

Tags: c, misra

Why the following code is the violation of MISRA 20.2 ?

```
#define abs(a)   (((a) < (0)) ? -(a) : (a))
```

As far as I understand from the topics , 20.2 does not concern with preprocessor identifier then why I get an violation for the same.

Comment: 20.2 = "don't reuse standard library macro and function names".  A MISRA checker would be pretty worthless if it didn't check macro soup.

Comment: Indeed. The MISRA rule is pretty self-explanatory. Read it.

Comment: @HansPassant : "Rule 20.2 refers to the declaration of non-preprocessor names. e.g. objects, function names, typedefs." This is the written on MISRA forum by MISRA group. Then why I get a violation?

Comment: abs() is a standard library function name, not a macro.  Do get with the spirit of the rule, this is equivalent to #define true false, just a lot harder to find.  The abs() function is not broken, consider just deleting the macro.

Comment: This *should* (IMHO) be a Rule 20.1 violation rather than a 20.2 - but I can appreciate why a tool might flag it for 20.2 as well...

Answer (score 2):

int `abs(int n)` is a standard library function in C, so you are not allowed to use the name '`abs`' for your own function or macro.

Answer (score 1):

This has also been asked on the [MISRA Forum](https://www.misra.org.uk/forum/viewtopic.php?f=71&t=1732), which has elicted the following "official" `MISRA C` answer :

> Rule 20.2 refers to the declaration of non-preprocessor names. i.e. objects, function names, typedefs. This code is not a violation of rule 20.2, but does violate rule 20.1 which does not permit standard library functions to be used in a #define.

Note: See profile for Disclaimer

Comment: Note that the code also causes undefined behaviour in ISO C, since standard library function names are reserved for use as macros by the implementation (C11 7.1.3/1).

Comment: It will generate "unexpected behaviour" as you are redefining a reserved feature - but I wouldn't say that this is "undefined behaviour" as defined by The Standard.

Comment: See C11 7.1.3/2 "If the program declares or defines an identifier in a
context in which it is reserved (other than as allowed by 7.1.4), or defines a reserved identifier as a macro name, the behavior is undefined."